# $location.search() setter not causing reload in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With **ngRoute**, using the `$location.search()` as a setter will cause a route reload and you can turn off this behaviour with `reloadOnSearch: false`.

However if I swap the `ngRoute` code with the above `ui-route` code, the controller no longer gets reloaded.

How I can trigger a route reload in ui-router **while keeping all the query parameters in the url** like ngRoute?

edit:
I need to keep the queries in the url, and unchanged after route reload because I want the user to be able to bookmark it.

```
/?people=bob&people=james&people=pete...&color=red&color=blue...etc
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute'])

// .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//     $stateProvider
//         .state('home', {
//             url: '/',
//             templateUrl: 'page1.html',
//             controller: 'MyController'
//         });

//         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
// }])

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'page1.html',
            controller: 'MyController'
            // reloadOnSearch: false
        });
})

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
        console.log('reloaded');
        $scope.changeQuery = function(testId) {
            $location.search('id', testId);
            console.log($location.absUrl());
        };
    }
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3>ui router</h3>
    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <h3>ng router</h3>
    <ng-view></ng-view>

</body>

</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<h1>Change query example</h1>
<input ng-model="testId" />
<button ng-click="changeQuery(testId)">Change!</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, instead of directly changing the $location, try to change the $state using $state.go(...)

Documented here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute']).config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/?key=:id',
        templateUrl: 'page1.html',
        controller: 'MyController'
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}]).controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$state', '$location',
function($scope, $state, $location) {
    console.log('reloaded');
    $scope.reload = function() {
      $state.reload();
    };

    $scope.changeQuery = function(testId) {
        $state.go('home', {id: testId});
        console.log($location.absUrl());
    };
}
]);
```

example:
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hPWoUQvUviA1KPCQJe9K?p=preview)

Comment: I need to keep the queries in the url, and unchanged after route reload because I want the user to be able to bookmark it.

sample url:
/?people=bob&people=james&people=pete...&color=red&color=blue...etc

Comment: In that case just use $state.reload()

Comment: Thank you very much. 
By adding `?key=:id` to the **state url**, location.search() now triggers a route reload

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the old query then whenever you want to change the query extend it and reload

```
var oldQuery = $location.search(); // save the current query
$scope.changeQuery = function(newQuery) {
  //whenever a new query comes, extend it and load the url again
  angular.extend(newQuery, oldQuery);
  $location.search(newQuery);
};
```